# Folland's real analysis book modes of convergence. Given sequence as uniformly convergent.

Tags: real-analysis

Folland's real analysis book gives $f_n = \chi_{(n,n+1)} $ on $\mathbb{R}$ as an example of **uniformly convergent** sequence. Intuitively it seems true, since as $n \rightarrow \infty$, the values on which $f_n$ takes $0$ is getting larger and larger and we expect it cover the whole $\mathbb{R}$. However I'm getting confused if I consider the formal definition. It is:
$$\forall \epsilon>0, \exists n_0 \in \mathbb{N}\text{ s.t. } \forall x \in \mathbb{R}, n>n_0 \implies |f_n(x)|< \epsilon.$$
Now for $\epsilon = 0.5 $ no matter how we choose $n_0$ we always find an $x$ in $\mathbb{R}$ (we may just pick any number in $(n,n+1)$), with $f_n(x) = 1 > \epsilon = 0.5$. And this contradicts with the definition.
What is my mistake here? I'll be very glad for any clarification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just as you say, the sequence does not converge uniformly on $\mathbb{R}$. As it converges to $0$ pointwise, the uniform limit would have to be $0$. Your argument shows exactly that this cannot happen. Alternatively notice that

$$\sup_{x\in\mathbb{R}}\rvert f_n(x)\rvert=1$$

for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$, so

$$\sup_{x\in\mathbb{R}}\rvert f_n(x)\rvert\not\to0$$

as $n\to\infty$.

Answer (score 1):

The domain of convergence matters here. If the claim is that $f_n$ converges uniformly on $\mathbb R$, then it’s of course false because $f_n(n+.1)=1$.